# Springboot API Input Regex validations fail after migration to Open API Swagger

Tags: regex, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have migrated my springboot application from springfox to springdoc-openapi-ui swagger and post which the input regex validations that I have on controller started failing and the openAPI swagger throws out an error stating the following validation message even if I supply the right input value

[image]

This is my springboot controller method signature

```
 public ServiceResponse<ResponseDTO> getNameByIdV2(
            @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}-]+$", flags = {Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE}, message = "INVALID ID")
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id
    )
```

Is there a way to fix this issue without changing the regex format or bypass/suppress swagger UI validations and let the backend handle validations and return a 400 error if the validation fails (Same behavior as springfox swagger)?

Comment: You should verify it supports simple properties first. Try `\p{L}` by itself. If it does, there may be a limited number of properties it supports.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support any of the \p{} regex formats. Hence, I wanted to know is there any way I can disable the swagger validations and let the backend perform validation & return 400 bad request if the validation fails. Springfox swagge never used to complain bad input and only backend used to return 400 error when the regex valdiation fails. I'm trying to achieve same behavior with openapi swagger as well.